# Inserting a datetime value within a datetime array Numpy Python

Tags: python, numpy, date, datetime, indexing

I want to insert the date `'2015-12-24 12:51:00'` as a datetime value within array `a`s first index how would I be able to do that and get to the Expected Output.  to the datetime array `a`

```
import numpy as np 
import datetime 

a = np.array(['2017-09-15 07:11:00', '2017-09-15 12:11:00', '2017-12-22 03:26:00',
 '2017-12-22 03:56:00', '2017-12-22 20:59:00', '2017-12-24 12:51:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
datetime = np.insert(a, 0, ('2015-12-24 12:51:00',dtype='datetime64[ns]'))
```

Error message:

```
  File "<ipython-input-5-ac3ba1f95707>", line 6
    datetime = np.insert(a, 0, ('2015-12-24 12:51:00',dtype='datetime64[ns]'))
                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Expected output:

```
['2015-12-24T12:51:00.000000000' '2017-09-15T07:11:00.000000000'
 '2017-09-15T12:11:00.000000000' '2017-12-22T03:26:00.000000000'
 '2017-12-22T03:56:00.000000000' '2017-12-22T20:59:00.000000000'
 '2017-12-24T12:51:00.000000000']
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to specify `dtype` on `insert`, that is basically what the error you get is saying. Just do `np.insert(a, 0, ('2015-12-24 12:51:00'))`

source: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html

Answer (score 0):

`np.array('2015-12-24 12:51:00',dtype='datetime64[ns]')` is the correct syntax for creating a datetime array.  `dtype` is a keyword parameter for the `np.array` function.

There are cases like `hstack` where you would want to cast this string to the correct dtype first, but `insert` does take care of that for you.  It has a line:

```
values = array(values, copy=False, ndmin=arr.ndim, dtype=arr.dtype)
```

Certainly no harm in doing the conversion yourself, just use the correct syntax.